# URL is not jumping to right number in Django

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20 )
    age=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Like(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    like=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Profile, Like
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    all_name=Profile.objects.all()
    context={'all_name':all_name}

    return render(request, 'database/index.html',context)

def detail(request, profile_id):

    all_likes=Like.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
    return render(request, 'database/detail.html', {'all_likes':all_likes})
```

**index.html**

```
  <h1>hey</h1>
       {% for name in all_name %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'database:detail' user.id %}">{{ name.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
```

**detail.html**

```
{{all_likes}}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name='database'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:profile_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

now *http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/index/* produces two list item,

but when I click on both, i am redirecting to *http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/1/* .

http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/2/ is working manually but not when I click. Couldn't figure out the error in the code.

Comment: You are using the same `user.id` in every link. I believe you wanted to write `name.id` instead of `user.id`.

Comment: name.id works. Thank you @Selcuk.

Comment: @Selcuk why can't we use age.id ?

Comment: `age` is not a model instance, it's an attribute of `Profile` class. You can do `name.age`. The confusion comes from your naming standard. Instead of calling a `Profile` object `name`, you should've chosen something like `profile`. That way you would write `profile.id` and `profile.age` which makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Selcuk I have been trying really hard to understand models and queries but I can see myself struggling here. Isn’t name is also an attribute of the class? user.id makes sense but how name.id returns the id but age.id doesn’t? If you can link good source or book to understand queries please give that as well. Django website still lacks to teach the queries for newbie like myself.

Comment: If you re-read my previous comment, it all boils down to your choice of confusing names. If you choose different variable names instead of `name` and `all_name` in `for name in all_name` the problem will go away. The `name` variable in that `for` loop and the `.name` attribute are totally different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass all objects to HTML:

```
all_name = Profile.objects.all()
```

and on for loop in HTML you used

```
{% for name in all_name %}
```

Here:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'database:detail' user.id %}">{{ name.name }}</a></li>
```

you are using `user.id` instead of `name.id`.

Use:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'database:detail' name.id %}">{{ name.name }}</a></li>
```

Then it will use the id of the object in for loop and will hit the correct URL.